# How to print single number only once using nested loops in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, nested, do-while

Everything runs fine in my Java code except at the very end of the code. So basically I can't figure out how to print out the User's Number if it is the same. For example I am prompt the User for a starting number and an ending number (integers). So say the user enters in the same integer "10" for starting number and "10" for ending number. I want the output to only be "10" to be printed only just once. I've tried everything I can think of with trying While Loop, Do-While Loop, and For Loops but I just can't figure it out?

------------------------JAVA CODE BELOW-------------------------------------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopsAssignment {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // input Scanner
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      // ask user for a starting number and a ending number
      System.out.println("Now I'll print whatever numbers you'd like!");
      System.out.println("Give me a starting number: ");
      startNum = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Give me an ending number: ");
      endNum = input.nextInt();

      // count the users range of numbers
      System.out.println("I counted your range of numbers: ");  
      int a = startNum;
      int b = endNum;

      while (a <= b) {
         System.out.println(a);
         a = a + 1;
      }
         while (a >= b) {
            System.out.println(a);
            a = a - 1;
         }
            while (a == b) {
               System.out.println(a); 
            }    

   }
}
```

---------------------OUT PUT BELOW -----------------------------------------------------

Now I'll print whatever numbers you'd like!
Give me a starting number: 
10
Give me an ending number: 
10
I counted your range of numbers: 
10
11
10

----jGRASP: operation complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure your code as follows:

```
  while (a < b) {
     System.out.println(a);
     a = a + 1;
  }

  while (a > b) {
     System.out.println(a);
     a = a - 1;
  }

  if (a == b) {
     System.out.println(a); 
  }
```

Comment: When I take out the equal signs it goes in an infinite loop? I need to code to print just the range. For example: startNum = 1, endNum = 10  //OUTPUT = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"

Comment: @DMJ did you actually try it? Note the use of 'if' instead of the last 'while'. I think you forgot to change your last 'while' to an 'if'.

Comment: It worked! You're right it was because I didn't change it to an if statement. I see where I was going wrong with my logic too because of the ">=" and "<=" in the expressions. That's why it caused those other extra numbers to print. Mahalo for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for loop`:

```
public static void printRange(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive) {
    for (; minInclusive <= maxInclusive; minInclusive++)
        System.out.println(minInclusive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are either counting up, down or there's just one.

So

```
int step = endNum>startNum ? +1 : -1;
int a = startNum;
int b = endNum;
while (a != b) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = a + step;
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Or put a `break` in the middle of a `for` loop. Also there's `+=`, and a few things we can make more conventional.

```
int step = endNum>startNum ? +1 : -1;

for (int i=startNum; ; i+=step) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (i == endNum) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your first two `while` loops where you are using "`>=`" and "`<=`". You can remove `"="` from the condition.

However you can improve your code as suggested in other comments.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I need those first two while loops because I need to count a users range of numbers if it goes.... For example: startNum = 1, endNum = 10  OR  startNum = 10, endNum = 1  OR  startNum = 10, endNum = 10